# Combine MHT-Files and Insert HTML

Tags: c#, html, email, mhtml

I am searching a way to combine two MHT-Files. I have one MHT-File and should insert one other at the beginning of it. Secondly I have to Insert a part of HTML (a HTML-Table) at the beginning.
I hope someone can help me.

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this now with the WPF RichEditControl of DevExpress.

Comment: Can you please explain how you did this? We are also using DevExpress and need to merge three MHT files. Thanks!

Comment: You can see it here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q389488